# How to push the fetched autocomplete data from JSON API to a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I am trying to fetch the values as Autocomplete jQuery method and store the selected input values into a text box (push to text box). Sounds easy but this JSON schema is kinda taking buzzy time.

Can I get a quick help here?

http://jsfiddle.net/ebPCq/1/

jQuery Code:

```
    $("#material_number").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                    return {
                        // following property gets displayed in drop down
                        label: item.name + ", " + item.countryName,
                        // following property gets entered in the textbox
                        value: item.name,
                        // following property is added for our own use
                        my_description: item.fcodeName
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure i understand what you're trying to do. Sorry. You want to be able to store the values the users press into the text box underneath?

Comment: This is all i could do for now, when i get your response, i'll work on it some more. http://jsfiddle.net/ebPCq/5/

Comment: @PedroEstrada Well try! You made it easier! Thanks man!

Comment: Err... no problem? jajaja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing up and finalizing the initial functionality, I came upon conclusion with this fiddle as the solution to my query posted above.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebPCq/7/

JS Code:

```
$(function () {
$("#input").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                    return {
                        // following property gets displayed in drop down
                        label: item.name + ", " + item.countryName,
                        // following property gets entered in the textbox
                        value: item.name,
                        // following property is added for our own use
                        my_description: item.fcodeName
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            $("#push-input").prepend(ui.item.value + '\r\n');
        }
    }
  });
});
```